# How can I split a mesh in several pieces so that all are smaller than a given number of vertices?

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh

I need to import a mesh to an app that can only handle a certain number of meshes per object. Because of that, I'm forced to split the mesh into several pieces until all pices are below the maximum vertex count. The splitting has to happen in runtime, so I can't use an external application to split the mesh.

I don't have any requirement regarding how the mesh is split, but it should conservate all faces, normals and UVs.

Is there any known algorithm that can do so?

Comment: Does your mesh make use of indices? Is it triangulated? If it is, you could iterate over the indices, copying each vertex pointed to by the current index into a new smaller mesh. You would 'finish' that mesh when the vertex count of the new mesh is greater than your max_vertex_count - 3.

Comment: @kirkroerig Yes, my mesh is triangulated. It is in the form of an ordered list of vertices, each including its uv coordinates. Faces are defined as groups of 3 indices of the vector list. Triangles are not correlative though, I can have a triangle with indexes 0, 300 and 1534 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a triangle adjacency graph. Start from a triangle and mark it visited. Then from each triangle side, move on adjacent triangles not visited and mark them visited. Once the vertex count reaches the limit, create a new mesh and start over.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility that is both simple to code and gives a reasonably good result is to sort the triangles spatially, with the Hilbert sort [1]. Then you traverse the ordered list of triangles, group them into clusters of n elements and generate the different parts of your mesh. An implementation is available in my GEOGRAM programming library [2]. See function mesh_partition() [3]. If you want to optimize the "compactness" of the parts (i.e. minimize the number of connected components in each part), then you can use a graph partitioning algorithm such as METIS [4] or SCOTCH [5], applied to the graph of the facets (that has a node per facet and an edge connecting each pair of adjacent facets). However, it is more expensive (in terms of both time and memory consumption).

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve

[2] http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html

[3] http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/mesh__partition_8h.html

[4] http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview

[5] http://www.labri.fr/perso/pelegrin/scotch/