# Runtime load of large, unsegmented mesh in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I have a mesh that is being generated from a point cloud scan of a room, depending on the size of the room the number of vertices can sometimes get to be larger than unity's supported max (650,000).

I can import these meshes into the editor, and unity automagically splits them down into sub-meshes. Is there a way to access this routine in a script at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

As what you have said, a mesh cannot contain more than 650,000 vertices at runtime or in editor.

At runtime, you should generate meshes in pieces. For example, given 100000 vertices, then you create the meshes like following:

```
// Your mesh data from the point cloud scan of a room
long[] indices = ...;
Vector3[] positions = = ...;

// Split your mesh data into two parts:
// one that have 60000 vertices and another that have 40000 vertices.

// create meshes
{
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    GameObject obj = new GameObject();
    obj.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh = mesh;
    var positions = new Vector3[60000];
    var indices = new int[count_of_indices];//The value of count_of_indices depends on how you split the mesh data.

    // copy first 60000 vertices to positions and indices

    mesh.vertices = positions;
    mesh.triangles = indices;
}
{
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    GameObject obj = new GameObject();
    obj.AddComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh = mesh;
    var positions = new Vector3[4000];
    var indices = new int[count_of_indices];

    // copy the remaining 40000 vertices to positions and indices

    mesh.vertices = positions;
    mesh.triangles = indices;
}
```

Comment: Just had a quick look at the linked classes,

Is it possible to use these within the app at runtime, or are they strictly for the editor?

Comment: They are only available in editor. I will update the answer.

Comment: Ahh, I was hoping I would not have to do this manually as deciding how to split a mesh is non-trivial.

Thanks for your help so far, do you have advice on how to split the mesh data?

Comment: Then that's another question. Maybe [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/559611/unity-splitting-mesh-into-2-parts.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532392/how-can-i-split-a-mesh-in-several-pieces-so-that-all-are-smaller-than-a-given-nu) can help. Or just google it or ask another question in SO.

Comment: This kind of operation (whilst super interesting!) is beyond the scope of my project.

I have ended up exporting the mesh's with .obj groups, then using Simple OBJ from the app store to quickly load them at runtime.

Comment: Yes.. Splitting mesh is a relatively complex task. Glad to know your problem has been soloved. :)